# Why can't I have a 'void' type here?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, equals, void

For some reason, I am getting this error: error: `'void' type not allowed here`.

This is in the `public static void main(String[] args){}`"method".

```
if(Arrays.equals(Arrays.sort(arrayCorrectLength1), arrayCorrectLength1) == false){
      System.out.println("Error.");
}
```

I have java.util.Arrays imported already. 
The program is supposed to take to string arrays and merge them, but first I need to check if they are in alphabetical order, so I check if the sorted version of the array is = to the original array. This is what I get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Arrays.sort` returns `void` hence it cannot be passed as an argument to `Arrays.equals`.

rather create a stream from the array, sort it, collect it into an array and then pass that as input to `Arrays.equals`.

```
if(!Arrays.equals(Arrays.stream(arrayCorrectLength1)
          .sorted().toArray(String[]::new), arrayCorrectLength1)){
         System.out.println("Error.");
}
```